# Passing Initial Data to Django Form After Instantiation

Tags: django, django-forms

Say I instantiate a Django Form in one of my views and can, conditionally, supply it with initial data. In the spirit of Not Repeating Myself, I would like to construct the form first and pass this information to the form later. What I would LIKE to do looks something like:

```
form = ThisForm()
if initial_data_element:
    initial_data = {
        'element': initial_data_element,
    }
    form.initial.update(initial_data)
```

What would be sub-optimal, but still answer my question, would be something that looks like:

```
form = ThisForm()
if initial_data_element:
    form.fields['element'].initial = initial_data_element
```

I was unable to find anything like this in the documentation or in other questions about forms here, which leads me to suspect that there is a different way that this class of problem is dealt with. For now I'll likely deal with it in the form's `__init__` method, but I think I'd prefer its construction be straightforward to follow in the view.

Worth mentioning is the reason I would *want* to do this: my traditional vector of approach of using a variable initialized to `None` is overwriting instance data in my ModelForm, and I'd really like to have a more robust solution.

My question: what is the recommended method of applying initial data to an already-instantiated form, if it is in fact even possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't reverse your logic and determine the initial data before instantiation? Really, that would be ideal.